# Product of Fréchet-Urysohn spaces is Fréchet-Urysohn

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Let $\{X_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in A}$ be a family of Fréchet-Urysohn spaces. Let $X=\prod_{\alpha\in A}X_\alpha$ then $X$ is Fréchet-Urysohn.

Proof.

Let $B=\prod_{\alpha \in A} B_\alpha\subseteq X,$ choose $x=(x_\alpha)_{\alpha\in A}\in \overline{B}=\prod_{\alpha \in A} \overline{B_\alpha}$. Since $X_\alpha$ is Frechet-Urysohn for all $\alpha\in A$ then, define the sequences $\{a_{n,\alpha}\}_{n\in \omega}$ such that $a_{n,\alpha} \xrightarrow{n\to \infty} x_\alpha$ for all $\alpha\in A$.

Define  $a_n:=(a_{n,\alpha})_{\alpha\in A}$ and choose the sequence $\{a_n\}_{n\in \omega}\subset C.$
Let us see that $a_n\xrightarrow{n\to \infty} x.$

Let $U$ a neighborhood of $x$ then, there exist a $J\subset A$ finite such that $U=\bigcap_{\alpha \in J} \pi_\alpha^{-1}(U_\alpha)$ for some open sets $U_\alpha\subset X_\alpha,\,\alpha \in J.$  Since $\{a_{n,\alpha}\}_{n\in \omega }\to x_\alpha$, for all $\alpha\in J$ there exist a $M_\alpha>0$ such that for all $j>M_\alpha$ then $a_{j,\alpha}\in U_\alpha$. Finally, let $L=\max_{\alpha \in J}\{M_\alpha\}$ and therefore, for all $j>L$ we have $a_{j,\alpha}\in U_\alpha$ for all $\alpha\in A.$ That is, $a_n$ converges to $x$ and thus, $X$ is Fréchet-Urysohn.

Answer (score 1):

It is not enough to consider sets of the form $\prod_{a \in A} B_a$ in your proof.

BTW, it's not even true that a product of Fréchet-Urysohn spaces is still Fréchet-Urysohn. Who gave you that idea? $[0,1]^{\omega_1}$ is a classic example of a product of metrisable spaces that is not even sequential..

According to [this paper](https://www.math.uh.edu/%7Ehjm/restricted/pdf31(2)/06liu.pdf) the product of first countable spaces *is* $\kappa$-Fréchet-Urysohn though. For definitions see the link.

Comment: Hi, the link doesnt work could you send me the name? Why it's not enough to consider those sets? Thank you!

Comment: @RafaCordoba The link still works for me though... It's  *$\kappa$-Fréchet-Urysohn spaces* by Liu and Ludwig in Houston Journal of Maths.. An arbitrary subset of a product is not a cube like that.